# Why doesn't onChange fire in one particular use case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, event-handling

In a small edit form, I prepopulate the Input elements with text values.  I then monitor the changes with each element's `onChange` event.

One strange phenomenon my QA colleague just discovered is that if you initially select all of the text (ie. Cmd-A or Ctrl-A) and then press Backspace or Delete, the `onChange` event is not fired.

This seems like a bug/defect in the browser or in React?

I'm going to combat it by adding an `onKeyUp` event handler for every Input element, looking for the Backspace (ASCII 8) or Delete (ASCII 46) codes.

**Update:**

It appears the root cause is my use of the `defaultValue` property, as in this example:

```
<Form.Control as='input'
              defaultValue={location}
              placeholder='Enter Location'
              onChange={e => handleChange(e)}

/>
```

With this code, the `onChange` event will not fire if the steps above are followed.  But if `defaultValue` is changed to `value` then everything works fine.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @RafaelMora If you read the Update section, you'll see that I answered the question myself.  I will not be using `defaultValue` anymore, only `value`.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my question that provides an explanation.

I'm not going to use the `defaultValue` of an Input element anymore!